# Show that For all real numbers $a, b$: If $0 < a < b$, then $\frac{a+b}{3} \in [a, b]$ is false by providing counter example.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, set-theory, examples-counterexamples

We are given few exercise questions that include statements that are false and we are required to prove it by providing counter example for each. Given below is statement is such.

**Statement**: For all real numbers $a, b$: If $0 < a < b$, then $\frac{a+b}{3} \in [a, b]$

**My Issue**: The issue is I have taken hours but I can't find any example and I tend to think that the statement might be true. It makes sense as well because a and b are positive when they are added and divided by $3$ we are basically dividing interval $[a, b]$ into $3$ intervals each with length equal to the $\text{answer}=\frac{(a+b)}{3}$ and hence it will lie in this interval of $[a,b]$ as well.

Who is wrong? My professor or I? Kindly guide.

Comment: $a=2, b=3$ is a counter-example.

Comment: $\frac{a+b}{3} \in [a, b]$ means $a \le \frac{a+b}{3} \le b$. Can you think of an example where the first relationship is wrong?

Comment: I guess the confusion here probaly comes from not understanding what an *interval* is. Or not understanding the notation $\frac{a+b}{3} \in [a, b]$.

Comment: Thanks. I kept trying with $a=1$ and changing values b. What a silly mistake.

Comment: @Ameer786: $a=1, b=1.5$ is also a counterexample.

Comment: @MartinR how are you coming up with all these and I don't? What am I missing while thinking about the solution? With what perspective do I approach this problem? I've got the solution but I want to the thought process.

Comment: @Ameer786: See my first comment. $a \le \frac{a+b}{3} \le b$ means $2a \le b$ **and** $a \le 2b$. The latter is always true if $a < b$, but the former not. So for a counterexample you must choose $b < 2a$.

Comment: How did you know that the latter statement is true if $a<b$, but former is not?

Answer (score 4):

When doing this question, I started with following test cases:

1. $a,b$ both positive and far apart relative to $0.$
2. $a,b$ both positive and close to each other, relative to $0.$

An example of Case $1$ is $a=1, b= 100$. But this fails to be a counter-example.

An example of Case $2$ is $a=100, b= 101$. Then, $(a+b)/3 \approx 67 \not\in [100,101].$ So this is a counter-example.

If none of these were counter-examples, you would have to keep coming up with qualitatively different test cases until you find one that is a counter-example (since the question tells you there is one).

Comment: +1 for the method as well as the answer. But (3) violates the hypothesis so isn't really a test case.

Comment: @EthanBolker true, answer edited.

Answer (score 3):

One way to think about the term $\frac{a+b}3$ is to rewrite it as $\frac{a+b+0}3$. In this form, it is clear that it is the average of $a, b$, and $0$. Finding a counterexample for $\frac{a+b}3\in [a,b]$ is to find $a,b$ which are close to each other and far from $0$.

Take $a=7, b=8$. Then $\frac{a+b}3=\frac{15}3=5\not\in[7,8]$.

Your intuition is *almost* correct, and the statement *would* hold if the denominator in the fraction was $2$ (since now we'd be taking the average of just $a$ and $b$, which is naturally somewhere between the two). It's just that division by larger numbers now pushes $\frac{a+b}n$ towards 0 and outside $[a,b]$.